# Exception depth in log4j

Tags: java, log4j

Im getting in instantiation exception inf our Myfaces 2 application. But the exception printing through log4j is cutting off the rest of the stacktrace. Here is what I am seeing:

> javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.InstantiationException
>           at org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildManagedBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:240)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanResolver.java:303)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanResolver.java:266)
>           at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:65)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.VariableResolverToELResolver.getValue(VariableResolverToELResolver.java:116)
>           at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
>           at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:61)
>           at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:107)
>           at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:85)
>           at javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:243)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:71)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:143)
>           at javax.faces.component.UISelectBoolean.getValue(UISelectBoolean.java:148)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getObjectValue(RendererUtils.java:238)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getBooleanValue(RendererUtils.java:193)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlCheckboxRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlCheckboxRendererBase.java:79)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:519)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:626)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:622)
>           at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:622)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1320)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:263)
>           at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:93)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
>           at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>           at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
>           at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:30)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.TomcatAnnotationLifecycleProvider.newInstance(TomcatAnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:49)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildManagedBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:162)
>           ... 48 more

I cannot find where to change the config so I can see the "... 48 more". Any ideas?

Comment: For those who wondered, you cannot have a myfaces managed bean as abstract. That is what this error was all about.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot. The truncation of the stack trace is a feature of the JVM, not log4j.

It's actually only discarding information that it has already presented to you.
The `... 48 more` is a shorthand for `the 48 frames that preceded the "Caused by" message`. So, in your case, the elided 48 frames are:

```
    org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.createManagedBean(ManagedBeanResolver.java:303) at
    org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.ManagedBeanResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanResolver.java:266) at
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54) at
    org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142) at
    org.apache.myfaces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:65) at
    org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.VariableResolverToELResolver.getValue(VariableResolverToELResolver.java:116) at
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54) at
    org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142) at
    org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:61) at
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:107) at
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186) at
    org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:85) at
    javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:243) at
    javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:71) at
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:143) at
    javax.faces.component.UISelectBoolean.getValue(UISelectBoolean.java:148) at
    org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getObjectValue(RendererUtils.java:238) at
    org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getBooleanValue(RendererUtils.java:193) at
    org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlCheckboxRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlCheckboxRendererBase.java:79) at
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:519) at
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:626) at
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:622) at
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:622) at
    org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1320) at
    org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:263) at
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59) at
    org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:93) at
    org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85) at
    org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239) at
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191) at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at
    org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349) at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) at
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) at
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128) at
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) at
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) at
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293) at
    org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190) at
    org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291) at
    org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769) at
    org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698) at
    org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891) at
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690) at
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: awesome thanks, I'll point to this answer since there are a few forums out there where its unanswered..