# Make IntelliJ Show Full Stack Trace During Failed JUnit Test

Tags: intellij-idea

When I run a Junit test and it fails, if the stacktace is super long, Intellij always cuts it off a the end with "... x More".  How can I make IntelliJ show the entire stacktrace?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getSharedCacheMode()Ljavax/persistence/SharedCacheMode;
    at org.hibernate.ejb.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInfo(LogHelper.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:526)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 54 more


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: I think it is not a problem with IntelliJ but a "feature" of the JVM. Consult [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4548624/1350762) for more information.

Comment: Perhaps you can handle exceptions in a special way - does JUnit provide a way to do this?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the Exception and run the test in Debug mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print full call stack on printStackTrace()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043378/print-full-call-stack-on-printstacktrace)

Answer (score 3):

I think, the "... x more" message occurs only when you have exceptions which are  wrapped by the previous exception. it means that the last x lines of the initial exception are the same as x lines missing in the caused by exception. It has nothing todo with IntelliJ. The jvm avoids repeating the trace info, as it does not provide new info.

[see also this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043378/print-full-call-stack-on-printstacktrace)