# How to see all lines of an error message on Intellij console?

Tags: java, intellij-14

I created a java project in intellij but am now getting an error that does not show all of the lines in the console:

```
12:40:52.227 [main] ERROR PostToDatabase - Error posting to database: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated string at line 1 column 126969 path $[207].null 
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated string at line 1 column 126969 path $[207].null
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:947)

Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated string at line 1 column 126969 path $[207].null
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1564)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextQuotedValue(JsonReader.java:1032)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextName(JsonReader.java:788)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:217)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:72)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
... 5 more
```

How do I access the `... 5 more`?

Comment: might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216411/make-intellij-show-full-stack-trace-during-failed-junit-test

Comment: Is this what you are asking about @Samantha?   This shows how to read the `... more` message: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1167917/179850

Comment: These are both helpful. Thank you!